# Is setState() necessary when updating this controller?

Tags: flutter, setstate

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and I've seen [examples](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app) where `setState()` is necessary. In the following code, `_bottomSheetController` is used to close the bottom sheet and is currently not updated inside `setState()`. Since it's a controller it doesn't hold any value that needs to be displayed in the UI - the controller is only used to call `_bottomSheetController?.close()` which apparently(?) causes the widget tree to be rebuilt. The code works as expected, but I don't know if `setState()` should be used anyway?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MapExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MapExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapExample> createState() => _MapExampleState();
}

class _MapExampleState extends State<MapExample> {
  PersistentBottomSheetController<void>? _bottomSheetController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      onTap: (position) {
        if (_bottomSheetController != null) {
          _bottomSheetController?.close();
          _bottomSheetController = null;
        }
      },
      markers: {
        Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('0'),
          position: const LatLng(0, 0),
          onTap: () {
            _bottomSheetController = Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
              (BuildContext context) {
                return const SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('BottomSheet'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        )
      },
      initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 11.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call setState in this case. You can also make MapExample Stateless Widget